# Use of と in 「音とといえば」 and 「普通の道徳と捉えていただいて結構」

Tags: particle-と

> 授業は粛々と進行している。音**と**といえば、黒板にチョークを走らせる音や、教科書をめくる音だけ。

音と vs just 音? Feels redundant if followed by といえば.

> A: 『宗教倫理』っていうのが時間割にあるけど、それは初めてだけどね
>
> B: それは普通の道徳**と**捉えていただいて結構よ。ミッション系としての特色はありますけどね

*Speaker asked about a religious morals class*

> As for the class, if you grasp normal morals (for us/the school) , that would be great ??  , ...

普通の道徳と... vs 普通の道徳が... ? hard to fit it as the quotative particle here.

The conditional usage feels similarly clunky for both sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

音とといえば is a simple typo. You don't need two と here. The sentence should be:

> 音といえば、黒板にチョークを走らせる音や、教科書をめくる音だけ。

---

> それは普通の道徳と捉えていただいて結構よ。
>   You can think of it as a normal (i.e., not particularly Christianity-related) moral class.

- **～と捉える**: "to regard (something) as ～", "to think of (something) as ～". This と is just a quotative particle. It's used with many verbs for thinking/regarding/interpreting (～と見なす, ～と解釈する, ...)
- **(te-form) + 結構です**: "It's okay to ～", "Feel free to ～".
- 道徳 here is one of the subjects taught at school, like 算数 (math), 体育 (PE) and 音楽 (music). See: [School subjects in Japan](https://ryohkei.tumblr.com/post/140237115829/school-subjects-in-japan)